# Current configured path for make install

Tags: gnu-make, autotools

How do I find the current configured path for make install?

The resources that I have read till now only describe how to overwrite it.

Comment: The question is overly vague. How do you find it as a user? As a package manager? As part of the build? Of the install?

Might also make more sense to ask what you're trying to achieve, as the answers may not be quite the same.

Comment: In context of the standard './configure & make & make install' method. I did the ./confgure (with a custom destination location as prefix) a few days ago. Is there a way to find it out the configured path where the executables will be installed?

Comment: That is still a huge surface of a question. You also have no answered on whether you're looking for a *human* or *programmatic* method.

Comment: Human. 
1. The installation of the software is already configured using the "./configure" command.
2. I have modified some source files and run the "make" step.
3. Now, I need to run the "make install" step and really, I just want to find out where the executable will be installed.

Comment: Sure, I can run the configure step again. I also found out that I can run "make -n install" to see the steps. But I just want to know if there's a more direct/appropriate method of doing this. I really don't understand how this is a surface question. I don't know how to give you the details that I don't even know exist. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

configure creates a file called config.log this contains near the top the configure command with the arguments that was run. You should find your --prefix argument there.

Otherwise grepping for PREFIX should get you a result.

Another solution is to use `make -n install` which would perform a dry run and print what make install would do without doing it.